# Better way to debug big JS files of a website than the chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to learn more about the inner workings of a website and the chrome dev tools (breakpoints, variable watching, call stacks etc.) are amazing. Couldn't wish for more. However, at huge files, the tools freeze which has been asked about many times.

I'm actually looking for alternatives on that. The debugger is perfect but its ability to break down over bigger files make it useless for this. A bit like `notepad.exe` on windows - the freezing is really arbitrary as computers can handle much more lines.

I've also noticed that `beautified` code causes less issues than minified one-liners so that might be the reason. But there is no way to display a minified version by default.

Comment: Should be possible to attach to a running tab (or start a new instance of the browser just while debugging) from a modern standalone IDE. Many of them support CDP (Chrome Debugging Protocol used by the built-in devtools) either inherently or via a plugin. Look for configuration tutorials.

Comment: did you solved it?